# Implement sizeForItemAtIndexPath in UICollectionView with custom layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uicollectionview

I have been struggling with this problem for last 5 days and unable to make any significant breakthrough.

Background:
I have a     UICollectionView with a custom layout. the UICollectionView has a textView for users to edit the cells content.

Issue:
I want to invoke the sizeForItemAtIndexPath but I am unable to do so. I have even extended the     UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol but still not able to get it working. Strange thing is that it works fine for a flowlayout

I would appreciate if you'll can help me to get further insights or point out where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To confirm, I changed the layout from custom to flow  and the method is invoked. Looks like sizeForItemAtIndexPath method is invoked only for flowlayout and not custom layout.